# Char.IsDigit vs NumberFormat.NativeDigits

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm working on optimizing my parser for JSON that I built in Visual Basic .NET. I do not follow the EBNF verbatim, for example with numbers I match for an optional positive sign and for boolean/null values I'm not limiting a match to just lower-case. However, I have a question on if I should use Char.IsDigit or NumberFormat.NativeDigits for matching digits in a number.

Currently I use Char.IsDigit because I'm iterating through each character in the source code and so it is just easier to compare the currently iterated Char value in the String. However, to check for the optional positive/negative signs I'm using the NumberFormat class anyways and so I was wondering if there is any benefit to checking if the currently iterated character is in the NativeDigits collection.

The downside that I can think of is that since I am iterating through each Char in the String, that I'd have to convert the Char to a String to check if the character is in the NativeDigits collection; since Strings are immutable in VB.NET I try to make as few instances of Strings as possible.

Comment: @the_lotus could you expand a little bit? I was unaware of any multiple character numbers.

Comment: My assumption about Unicode was wrong, I tested with culture prs-AF and it seems to be no different. I retracted what I said and will let someone more knowledgeable answer.

Comment: @the_lotus, The documentation for [NumberFormat.NativeDigits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.nativedigits?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_NumberFormatInfo_NativeDigits) alludes to the possibility of a surrogate pair of characters that correspond to the western digits, so your deleted concern was valid.  Even if that where not true, the question premise that a Char value would need to be converted to a String for comparison is pure folly.

Comment: @TnTinMn - See the following: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hfyxgm

Comment: @David, [Array.FindIndex Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex?view=netframework-4.7.2) or you could just prepare a `Char()` and use that.  However, if you need to support mult-character numbers, write a custom `IndexOf`.  Don't limit yourself to built-in functions.